# A second order double variable ODE.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $\exists$ two double differentiable  functions $F,G$. Let $F(0)=f,F'(0)=f',F''(0)=f''$, similarly define for $G$. It is given that
$$fg=2,f'=2g'=4g,g''=5f''=6f=3$$ Find all such $F,G$.

I assumed $F(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}k_ie^{\lambda_i x}$ and for $G(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}l_ie^{\mu_i x}$ . There were $4n$ variables for each $n$  and $6$ equations.So, I concluded infinitely many functions possible.

Is it okay to assume $F,G$ like that since every function can be converted to $\sum_{i=1}^{n}k_ie^{\lambda_i x}$? If not, how could I solve this?

Comment: Something does not appear right here. $F$ is a function, and so $F(0)$ is a number, but I don't understand how $F(0)$ can be equal to the function $f$ ? Are you sure that $F$ is supposed be defined as the antiderivative of $f$ ?

Comment: @VivekKaushik $f$ is also a number not a function $\left(\text{here }f=\sum_{i=1}^{n}k_i\right)$

Comment: So all you're restricting are the values of $F$ and $G$ and their first and second derivatives at $0$?  Just find the possible values of $f, g, f', g', f'', g''$, Then take $F(x) = f + f' x + f'' x^2/2 + x^3 H(x)$ where $H$ is any twice-differentiable function, and similarly for $G$.

Comment: (Actually $H$ need not be twice-differentiable at $0$, as long as $x^3 H(x)$ is and its first and second derivatives there are $0$).

Comment: $f'=4g=8/f\,\Rightarrow\, f'f=8\ \iff\ (f^2/2)'=8\ \Rightarrow\ f^2/2=8x+c_1\ \Rightarrow f(x)=\pm\sqrt{16x+c_0}$ so without initial values condition you have infinite solutions since c_0 must be determined by initial conditions.

Comment: @Joako $f$ is a number not a function.

Comment: @Chesx Then $f'$ is notation and not a derivative? (otherwise $f'=0$ if $f$ is a number)... Same happen for $F'(0)$? it is not the derivative of $F$ at $x=0$?